# How to add n rows to a data grid view in one call?

Tags: c#

I have a **DataGridView** named **dvg**.

After executing `dvg.Rows.Clear()`, I would like to add n number of rows with no data (Data shall be populated later). Is there any single function call which can do this?

Comment: No.  Write a for loop and put your single function call for a single row in the loop.  Takes two lines of code.

Comment: Thank you. The code I have is with the for loop. When executed, it takes more than 2 seconds to complete the loop, due to the large number of rows (25k rows). So I have been told to rewrite this in a more efficient way :(

Comment: `dgv.RowCount = n;` ?

Comment: @dr.null This work for me. Thank you.  If you can post this an answer. I will accept.

Comment: Very well. You are welcome. You do that please.

Comment: @dr.null : Done. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`dgv.RowCount = n;` solved the issue. Thanks to comment from dr.null